# Node/Express.js does not display images on production server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, production-environment

I have a problem with my `MERN` stack application. the images in the root express application displays on development environment but when i deploy my application on `heroku` the images refuses to display. I served the images statically by using `app.use(express.static('images'))` but it still does not display on the production environment.
Here is the `index.js` file on the express backend.

```js
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use('/images/profilephotos', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images/profilephotos')));
app.use('/images/productimages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images/productimages')));
app.use('/images/postimages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images/postimages')));
app.use('/images/coverimages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images/coverimages')));
```

this is how i require the images on the frontend which is react.

```js
  if(posts) {
   renderPosts = posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post._id} className="homeposts__box">
                {post.image ? <img className="homeposts__img" src={'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/' + post.image} alt="Article image" /> : null }
                <div className="homeposts__contentbox">
                  <h6>Article</h6>
                  <h3><NavLink to={'/blog/' + post._id}>{post.title}</NavLink></h3>
                  {post.tags ? post.tags.map(tag => <span className="homeposts__tags">{tag}</span>) : null}
                  <p>{post.body}<NavLink to={'/blog/' + post._id}>Read More</NavLink></p>
                  <span>by <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {post.firstName + ' ' + post.lastName} </span> • <Moment format="MMM D YYYY">{post.createdAt}</Moment> • Comments: <span style={{ color: '#082e40'}}>{post.comments}</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      } else {
         renderPosts = <Skeleton count={4}/>
      }
```

i have also tried using on the relative path which i expected to work

```js
  if(posts) {
   renderPosts = posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <div key={post._id} className="homeposts__box">
                {post.image ? <img className="homeposts__img" src={post.image} alt="Article image" /> : null }
                <div className="homeposts__contentbox">
                  <h6>Article</h6>
                  <h3><NavLink to={'/blog/' + post._id}>{post.title}</NavLink></h3>
                  {post.tags ? post.tags.map(tag => <span className="homeposts__tags">{tag}</span>) : null}
                  <p>{post.body}<NavLink to={'/blog/' + post._id}>Read More</NavLink></p>
                  <span>by <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}> {post.firstName + ' ' + post.lastName} </span> • <Moment format="MMM D YYYY">{post.createdAt}</Moment> • Comments: <span style={{ color: '#082e40'}}>{post.comments}</span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      } else {
         renderPosts = <Skeleton count={4}/>
      }
```

Please i need to know how to serve these images statically on production server from my express backend.

Comment: try to fetch the image thru url in browser

Answer (score 1):

Can you please share sample data like what's in post.image.

Also, you don't need to define a static server for every subfolder if you are defining the root of it like below.

`app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));`

Comment: images/coverimages/fd77fa88-8628-45a4-8f40-3fd46e525792interracialonbeach-1024x538.jpg. this is the post.image

Comment: What happend if you put this url in browser directly, did it show the image?

like localhost:PORT/images/coverimages/fd77fa88-8628-45a4-8f40-3fd46e525792interracialonbeach-1024x538.jpg

Comment: yes it works but in production it doesnt work with the site url

Comment: By the way, where you are uploading your images?

Comment: the application is deployed to heroku. i guess that where the images are

Comment: Heroku is not persistence storage server so images have been already deleted when it restarted.

Comment: You need to use third party services like Cloudinary.

Comment: thanks i just checked out cloudinary. i think that will work for me

Answer (score 1):

`src={'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/' + post.image}`

instead

`` src={`/${post.image}`} ``

This should work and your `post.image` should have `/images` slug in it or you need to append that too to the above src